# cropping multiple open documents in photoshop when making the first selection

Tags: photoshop-script

the script I am making should do this
PDF-to psd (ok)
all documents stays open (ok)
the user make a selection what defines the crop for every open documents in Photoshop (not ok)
close and save in an other folder(ok)

The idea is that we have pdf's that we wound to crop in a certain way. But next time we will have other pdfs that has to be cropped in a different way. this what I 'have got so far but it's crops the documents like a set in the parameters.

thanks

```
 //PDFOpenOptions.jsx
        var OpenAIFile = new PDFOpenOptions;
        OpenAIFile.antiAlias = false;
        OpenAIFile.mode = OpenDocumentMode.CMYK;
        OpenAIFile.resolution = 150;

    var myFolder = Folder.selectDialog("select folder");

    if(myFolder != null)
    {
      var fileList = myFolder.getFiles(/\.(pdf)$/i);
      for(var i = 0 ;i < fileList.length; i++)
      {
        if(fileList[i] instanceof File)
        {
          var doc= open(fileList[i],OpenAIFile);
        }
      }
    };

var outputFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Dossier de destination:");

//alert(outputFolder);

if (app.documents.length > 0) {
//flatten the active document
app.activeDocument.flatten();


//jpeg options
var myJPEGOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
myJPEGOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
myJPEGOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;
myJPEGOptions.matte = MatteType.WHITE;
myJPEGOptions.quality = 12;
myJPEGOptions.scans = 3;

// get documents;
var docs = app.documents;
for (var m = 0; m < app.documents.length; m++) {
app.activeDocument = docs[m];

try {

//crop 1Lsquaire-got from script lisner
var idCrop = charIDToTypeID( "Crop" );
var desc4 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idT = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
    var desc5 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idTop = charIDToTypeID( "Top " );
    var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
    desc5.putUnitDouble( idTop, idPxl, 601.000000 );
    var idLeft = charIDToTypeID( "Left" );
    var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
    desc5.putUnitDouble( idLeft, idPxl, 2068.000000 );
    var idBtom = charIDToTypeID( "Btom" );
    var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
    desc5.putUnitDouble( idBtom, idPxl, 2948.000000 );
    var idRght = charIDToTypeID( "Rght" );
    var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
    desc5.putUnitDouble( idRght, idPxl, 2918.000000 );
var idRctn = charIDToTypeID( "Rctn" );
desc4.putObject( idT, idRctn, desc5 );
var idAngl = charIDToTypeID( "Angl" );
var idAng = charIDToTypeID( "#Ang" );
desc4.putUnitDouble( idAngl, idAng, 0.000000 );
var idDlt = charIDToTypeID( "Dlt " );
desc4.putBoolean( idDlt, false );
var idcropAspectRatioModeKey = stringIDToTypeID( "cropAspectRatioModeKey" );
var idcropAspectRatioModeClass = stringIDToTypeID( "cropAspectRatioModeClass" );
var idtargetSize = stringIDToTypeID( "targetSize" );
desc4.putEnumerated( idcropAspectRatioModeKey, idcropAspectRatioModeClass, idtargetSize );
executeAction( idCrop, desc4, DialogModes.ALL );
//crop 1Lsquaire


//save file to folder
var myFile = new File((outputFolder ) + "/" + activeDocument.name);
app.activeDocument.saveAs(myFile, myJPEGOptions, true);

}

catch (e) {
alert ("Error the script did not execute");
}

}

while(documents.length>0){
   documents[documents.length-1].close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
}

};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can work out where the crop co-ordinates need to be and then apply them as you see fit. If you change the script-listener crop code to a function you can pass in those co-ordinates. Just add another line for the second set of crops and either save as a new script, or just comment them out

```
// usage:
selectRectangle(601, 2068, 2948, 2918);
cropToSelection();

// function SELECT RECTANGLE(top, left, bottom, right)
//
// Note: co-ordinates are same as script listener
// and not so human-friendly as t,l,r,b.
// --------------------------------------------------------
function selectRectangle(top, left, bottom, right)
{
  // deselect EVERYTHING first
  app.activeDocument.selection.deselect();

  // =======================================================
  var id1 = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
  var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id2 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
  var ref1 = new ActionReference();
  var id3 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
  var id4 = charIDToTypeID( "fsel" );
  ref1.putProperty( id3, id4 );
  desc1.putReference( id2, ref1 );
  var id5 = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
  var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id6 = charIDToTypeID( "Top " );
  var id7 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
  desc2.putUnitDouble( id6, id7, top );
  var id8 = charIDToTypeID( "Left" );
  var id9 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
  desc2.putUnitDouble( id8, id9, left );
  var id10 = charIDToTypeID( "Btom" );
  var id11 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
  desc2.putUnitDouble( id10, id11, bottom );
  var id12 = charIDToTypeID( "Rght" );
  var id13 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
  desc2.putUnitDouble( id12, id13, right );
  var id16 = charIDToTypeID( "Rctn" );
  desc1.putObject( id5, id16, desc2 );

   executeAction( id1, desc1, DialogModes.NO );

}

function cropToSelection()
{
  executeAction( charIDToTypeID( "Crop" ), new ActionDescriptor(), DialogModes.NO );
}
```